# Deserializing a json string with restsharp

Tags: c#, json, rest, asp.net-web-api, restsharp

I have a string that comes out of a database which is in Json format.

I have tried to deserialize it with:

```
RestSharp.Deserializers.JsonDeserializer deserial = new JsonDeserializer();
var x = deserial .Deserialize<Customer>(myStringFromDB)
```

But the `.Deserialize` function expects an `IRestResponse`

Is there a way to use RestSharp to just deserialize raw strings?

Comment: I feel your pain

Answer (score 74, accepted):

There are sereval ways to do this. A very popular library to handle json is the [`Newtonsoft.Json`](http://json.codeplex.com/). Probably you already have it on your asp.net project but if not, you could add it from `nuget`.

Considering you have a response object, include the following namespaces and call the static method `DeserializeObject<T>` from `JsonConvert` class:

```cs
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using RestSharp;
```

```cs
return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(response.Content);
```

On the `response.Content`, you will have the raw result, so just deserialize this string to a json object. The `T` in the case is the type you need to deserialize.

For example:

```cs
var customerDto = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CustomerDto>(response.Content);
```

**Update**

Recently, Microsoft has added a namespace `System.Text.Json` which handle json format on the .Net platform. You could use it calling the `JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>` static method:

```cs
using System.Text.Json;
```

```cs
var customer = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Customer>(jsonContent);
```

Comment: The RestSharp serializer and deserializer was the problem. By using Newton soft the problem went away.

Comment: @BahaiResearch.com It's not that RestSharp's serializer/deserializer has/is a problem per se; it just doesn't have the functionality you need, since RestSharp is an http client library not a general serialization tool.  As you pointed out it requires an `IRestResponse`, as opposed to let's say supporting an IRestResponse.Content (string type) as well.  StevieJ81 below points out a potential way workaround if for some reason you want to or must use RestSharp for json deserialization: he directly plugs IRestResponse.Content.

Comment: Using the native `System.Text.Json` in .NET 6 LTS and it works wonderful.

Answer (score 58):

If you want to avoid using extra libraries, try this:

```
RestSharp.RestResponse response = new RestSharp.RestResponse();

response.Content = myStringFromDB; 

RestSharp.Deserializers.JsonDeserializer deserial = new JsonDeserializer();

Customer x = deserial.Deserialize<Customer>(response);
```

Caveats apply - not extensively tested - but seems to work well enough.

Comment: Works great.  One less library I have to include in my application.

Comment: In the version of RestSharp I'm using it looks like the JsonDeserializer class has been moved to RestSharp.Serialization.Json.JsonDeserializer

Comment: I don't think this is valid anymore, at least for version "100.6.10"

Comment: In my case the RestSharp deserializer handles funky object names in the json content much better than the Newtonsoft deserializer, so that's another argument not to include another library just for this.