# Deserialize a JsonResult from C#

Tags: c#, json, .net, restsharp

I access a REST API with this code :

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> NetExplorerAPI(string AdresseAPI, object Requete, RestSharp.Method Methode)
{
    var client = new RestClient(AdresseAPI);

    var request = new RestRequest();
    request.Method = RestSharp.Method.Post;
    request.AddJsonBody(Requete);
    request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            
    //request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer a844024a4e744182aeaa62dd6347b9049f9ba35650339d2b9362e1bf03a92ac0");
    //IRestResponse response = await client.ExecuteAsync(request);

    RestResponse response = await client.ExecuteAsync(request);
            
    JsonResult jr = new JsonResult(response);
            
    return (jr);
}
```

I want to deserialize the JsonResult to get the token in a string :

```json
{ "token": "med6RRIikrZ-2tua9jUa6pVZubnPvhqSH6wHvtkH42TNfJGXOaI-GioUKPvfbhP7XiGG6UgjCzUnJt87kwsljQBAKEb" }
```

But When I serialize the JsonResult I get a lot of items I don't need to :

```cs
string s = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jr);
```

```
{"ContentType":null,"SerializerSettings":null,"StatusCode":null,"Value":{"ContentType":null,"SerializerSettings":null,"StatusCode":null,"Value":{"Request":{"AlwaysMultipartFormData":false,"MultipartFormQuoteParameters":false,"FormBoundary":null,"Parameters":[{"DataFormat":0,"ContentEncoding":null,"Name":"","Value":{"user":"sylvain.krier@protonmail.com","password":"S@r@line2004"},"Type":3,"Encode":false,"ContentType":"application/json"},{"Name":"Accept","Value":"application/json","Type":2,"Encode":false,"ContentType":null}],"Files":[],"Method":1,"Timeout":0,"Resource":"","RequestFormat":0,"RootElement":null,"OnBeforeDeserialization":null,"OnBeforeRequest":null,"OnAfterRequest":null,"Attempts":1,"CompletionOption":0,"ResponseWriter":null,"AdvancedResponseWriter":null},"ContentType":"application/json","ContentLength":103,"ContentEncoding":[],**"Content":"{\"token\":\"wlK4LIRpOxqKOwJ2Hs554l5-WI--IrqHW7TECZ3YtdS-RpzDuQGaQeLI0qjo8NzaSPhCUYaarBcXstrI5sPlXkwCmk9\"}"**,"StatusCode":200,"IsSuccessful":true,"StatusDescription":"Ok","RawBytes":"eyJ0b2tlbiI6IndsSzRMSVJwT3hxS093SjJIczU1NGw1LVdJLS1JcnFIVzdURUNaM1l0ZFMtUnB6RHVRR2FRZUxJMHFqbzhOemFTUGhDVVlhYXJCY1hzdHJJNXNQbFhrd0NtazkifQ==","ResponseUri":"https://patrimoine-click.netexplorer.pro/api/auth","Server":"Apache","Cookies":[],"Headers":[{"Name":"Date","Value":"Tue, 19 Jul 2022 06:40:36 GMT","Type":2,"Encode":false,"ContentType":null},{"Name":"Server","Value":"Apache","Type":2,"Encode":false,"ContentType":null},{"Name":"Pragma","Value":"no-cache","Type":2,"Encode":false,"ContentType":null},{"Name":"Cache-Control","Value":"no-store, must-revalidate, no-cache","Type":2,"Encode":false,"ContentType":null},{"Name":"X-NetExplorer-Version","Value":"7.4.4.12","Type":2,"Encode":false,"ContentType":null},{"Name":"Access-Control-Allow-Origin","Value":"*","Type":2,"Encode":false,"ContentType":null},{"Name":"X-UA-Compatible","Value":"IE=edge,chrome=1","Type":2,"Encode":false,"ContentType":null},{"Name":"Connection","Value":"close","Type":2,"Encode":false,"ContentType":null},{"Name":"X-Content-Type-Options","Value":"nosniff","Type":2,"Encode":false,"ContentType":null},{"Name":"Transfer-Encoding","Value":"chunked","Type":2,"Encode":false,"ContentType":null}],"ContentHeaders":[{"Name":"Expires","Value":"Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT","Type":2,"Encode":false,"ContentType":null},{"Name":"Content-Type","Value":"application/json","Type":2,"Encode":false,"ContentType":null},{"Name":"Content-Length","Value":"103","Type":2,"Encode":false,"ContentType":null}],"ResponseStatus":1,"ErrorMessage":null,"ErrorException":null,"Version":"1.1","RootElement":null}}}
```

I don't know how to get the "content" item.

Comment: Did you try `response.Content` and then deserialize it to JSON?

Comment: Yes, you need to deserialize ```response.Content``` https://stackoverflow.com/a/16530226/7357322

Answer (score 3):

From RestSharp's official [QuickStart](https://restsharp.dev/intro.html#basic-usage):

> When using typed `ExecuteAsync<T>`, you get an instance of `RestResponse<T>` back, which is identical to RestResponse but also contains the T Data property with the deserialized response.
>
> None of `ExecuteAsync` overloads throw if the remote server returns an error. You can inspect the response and find the status code, error message, and, potentially, an exception.
>
> Extensions like `GetAsync<T>` will not return the whole `RestResponse<T>` but just a deserialized response. These extensions will throw an exception if the remote server returns an error. The exception will tell you what status code was returned by the server.

It looks like you have to choices:

1. Use `client.ExecuteAsync` and then `response.Data`
2. Use `client.GetAsync<T>`

For client.GetAsync you'll need a new type. For exmaple

```
public class MyTokenClass { public string token {get; set;} }
```

and then `var t = await client.GetAsync<MyTokenClass>()`.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you looking for let me know if you need something specific.

```
string theToken = JObject.Parse(response.Content)["token"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

When you get a Response object from  ExecuteAsync, response is already deserialized into c# Response class, but Content is not. In this case Content contains a json string. You can parse the string to get a token (or deserialize it if you create a custom class)

This code will return { "token": "med6RRIikrZ-2tua9jUa6p...} as an ActionResult

```
string token = (string)JObject.Parse(response.Content)["token"];
return Ok( new { token = token});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return `JsonResult` with the `Content` property of `RestResponse`:

```
return new JsonResult(response.Content);
```